# on duplicate key update fails with error "Cannot add or update a child row"

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table with a compound primary key "name" and "id". The fields are actually "name","id","phone","amount","units","alias". I have the query

```
 insert into MyTable (name,id,phone,amount) select "henry" as name, id,phone,amount from anotherTable
 on duplicate key update phone=values(phone),amount=values(amount).
```

MySQL spits the following error:

```
 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
```

BTW, "id" is a foreign key.

Any help?

as requested below, the schema for other table is

```
 CREATE TABLE `otherTable` (
 `otherId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `DOBId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bankAccount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `partialAmount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `notes` varchar(299) DEFAULT NULL,
 `latitude` decimal(8,5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `longitude` decimal(8,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`otherId `),
  KEY `DOBId ` (`DOBId `),
  KEY `bankAccount ` (`bankAccount `),
  KEY `id ` (`id `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3305 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

for myTable

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `appleNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `windowsNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pens` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pencils` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `myTable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `yet_another` (`id`)
```

Comment: Can you post the schema of `MyTable`?

Comment: Why is myTable.name an int(11)?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the real table; not allowed to post the actual names. the definition is accurate but I changed the names on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the FK constraint you have on `myTable` is referencing the ids of `yet_another`, so when you are inserting ids from `anotherTable` you are breaking this FK constraint. Chances are there are ids in `anotherTable` that do not exist in `yet_another` table.

Understand this is a shot in the dark, based on the abstracted schema you posted. If you want a more solid answer, I'd have to see the actual schema.

Answer (score 0):

The on duplicate key applies to the primary key. I take it you're using innodb. This is failing on a foreign key constraint. Which values of you table MyTable are foreign keys?   Please post the create statement for the table that shows all keys and constraints for more detailed help.

Just a guess, but for grins I'm betting it's a column that's not in the insert that is a foreign key not allowing a null value.